# Insert something between items int a list with typescript

Tags: typescript

I have list of something and wanna insert something between items. I can do it by reduce:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.reduce((all, cur) => [
  ...(all instanceof Array ? all : [all]),
  0,
  cur
])
```

In first iteration `all` contains the first item and have type `number`, but in next iterations it is the list. You can see it by logging:

```
arr.reduce((all, cur) => {
  console.log(all);
  return [
    ...(all instanceof Array ? all : [all]),
    0,
    cur
  ]
});
// 1
// [1, 0, 2]
// [1, 0, 2, 0, 3]
```

It works in pure JS, but i can't use it with TypeScript. If I try to type it:

```
arr.reduce((all: number | number[], cur: number) => [
    ...(all instanceof Array ? all : [all]),
    0,
    cur
]);
```

... I get the error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(all: number | number[], cur: number) => number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: number, currentValue: number, currentIndex: number, array: number[]) => number'.   Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In typescript, when you reduce an array and don't give initial value (i.e the initial value is the first entry of your array), so the type of the previousValue (here "all") is the same type than the type of the first entry of the array. I don't think you can change it, you have to change your function for something with an initialValue as an array like :

```
const arr: number[] = [1,2,3]
arr.reduce((all, cur, index) => index === 0
    ? [cur]
    : [...all, 0, cur]
,[])
```

Comment: It works, but it's necessary explicitly specify the type `all: number[]` (typescript 4.2.3)